# Login User with Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

The app is supposed to accept the user email and password and uses firebase authentication as back end. I'm using pixel 2 as emulator. It  crashes every time the app processes the sign in function.

Below is the Java file and gradle file

Java File:

[image: 1st Part]

```
    private void loginUser() {

        //initializing views
        EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: Post your Error logs, from logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the OnCreate method you should initialize the Firebase Auth.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

You are using mAuth inside loginUser method but it's not initialized. That could be one reason for the crash.